# WARNING ON : npm install --save angular-calendar

Tags: node.js, angular, calendar

In angular 4 app , I need to use calendar control in a form. while i try to install npm for calendar control, facing the below mentioned warning. 
I could ignore the warning but then i don't see angular-calendar installed in my node_modules for which am unable to import the required modules. 
Below is the error for reference, Any help would be appreciated. 
Am using

```
NPM version : '3.10.10'
Node version : '6.11.0'
```

Message:

```
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
```

Comment: fsevents does not run on windows, but that warning is commonly seen.  You can safely ignore it and I can almost guarantee it's not the reason for angular-calendar not installing correctly.

Comment: thank you for your response,problem was the path i was using out of node_modules while i installing angular-calendar.